# Routing(forwarding) all traffic based on source/destination (Linux/CentOS)

Tags: centos, iptables

I have an active-active Linux router (running CentOS) with three interfaces (ens100, ens101, ens102). I use iptables to route traffic.

My problem is with connections between "Server A" and "Server B". I can't ping "Server B" from from "Server A" but I can ping "Server B" from the "Linux router". I can also see that there are packets coming from "Server B" to "Server A" through "Linux Router" ens100 interface

I think this is because "Server B" has a default gateway on "Switch A" hence traffic from "Server B" is routed via "Switch A", "Switch B" and finally through the "Linux Router". But because "Linux Router" has an interface in the same network as "Server B" all traffic destined from "Server A" to "Server B" will bypass "Switch B" and "Switch A" routing. That seems to brake things.

I would like to do some kind of conditional forwarding or policy based routing on "Linux Router" so that traffic sourced from "Server A" to 10.2.0.0/24 would be routed/forwarded to "Switch B" i.e through ens100 and not through ens102 (default route interface for network 10.2.0.0/24 on "Linux-Router).

[Network schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl1lr.png)

Comment: I won't be able to answer this (especially with devices described as switch but sometimes routing (switchB) sometimes switching and routing (switchA has 2 IPs, not 3)). What I'm sure about in my comment: please *do forget iptables*. `iptables` is not routing. The routing stack is routing. What you might be looking for is policy/source-based routing. I can't be sure you need it because I was lost in the explanations. If you need it it's implemented with `ip rule ... lookup XXX` and `ip route ... table XXX`: additional routing tables used by policy rules.

Comment: Also what is the meaning of "active-active router" in this context? I would have thought that means there are *two* of them, but you're talking about a single CentOS router.

Comment: Actualy there are two identical CentOS virtual machines, with identical iptables configurations but in this case this actually is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me to the right direction! I remember doing some policy based routing in the past with another system and just tried with this one and I got it working. Basically I had to create a new routing table, tie the table with "Server A" network as source and copy the main routing table entries to the new one replacing the 10.2.0.0/24 route with a one via default gateway instead of link src 10.2.0.252.

Comment: You should answer your own question then and tell how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

As A.B commented - the solution (not sure if the only one) was to use policy based routing.

Step 1: add a new table to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` with an unused id, in my case `105 appstest`

Step 2: force the new routing table to be used on connections from the network "Server A" resides: 
`ip rule add from 10.5.0.0/24 table appstest`

Step 3: add the routes from the main table but replace the:

`10.2.0.0/24 dev ens102 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.252 metric 102` with

`10.2.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.254 dev ens100 proto static metric 102`

so the commands become:

`ip route add default via 10.8.0.254 dev ens100 proto static metric 100 table appstest`

`ip route add 10.2.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.254 dev ens100 proto static metric 102 table appstest`

`ip route add 10.5.0.0/24 dev ens101 proto kernel scope link src 10.5.0.254 metric 101 table appstest`

The metrics are my setup specific. Hope this helps someone.